# Preventing button click before timeout function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application that takes a few seconds to get some data and then puts it on the screen.  I also have a back button that allows the user to basically return to the previous screen.  I want this button to be disabled while the timeout function works.  How would I go about doing this?  As I have it now, the button still works, even while the information is being gathered.  Here's what I have.

**JS**

```
$("#areas").on("change", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#back").on("click", function(event){
        $(this).disabled = true;
    }, 3000)
})
```

Comment: Don't enable it unless you get the data. Makes sense ?

Comment: I think that you need to share the code that retrieves the data in asynchronous call

Comment: If you're using AJAX to get the data, you can use the function callback `complete` to re-enable your button after the call has completed.

Comment: @Abhitalks, oops.  Forgot to copy that part.  corrected the question code

Comment: @Robert: Also, please clarify how are you getting your data?

Comment: @Abhitalks asynchronously

Comment: @robert: in that case follow the advice of AdamMazzarella in the comment above.

Comment: I'm not using AJAX though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does following rings any bells?

```
$("#back").prop("disabled", true);
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(){

        // ..Gathere the information

        $("#back").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

I also recommend you to hardcode disabled="disabled" in HTML itself so you don't need first line in above code.

```
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="BACK" id="back">
```

[EDIT]

I see you don't use ajax method. But I think you do know where the data process starts and finish so just put prop method call there.

```
$("#area").append(newContent); // wild guess you final code
$("#back").prop("disabled", false);
```

In case you have no choice to add the line, there is another solution which I haven't tried before, though.

```
$('#area').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    // Some condition indecates the process has done
    if ( ... ) {
        $("#back").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

note: confirm the supported browser of DOMSubtreeModified

Answer (score 0):

You need to onclick inside setTimeout also you should give delay to setTimeout function. Simply disable button till timeout works!

Try below

```
$("#areas").on("change", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#back").attr('disabled','disabled');
    },2000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#back` button is disabled, and enabled after 10s.

```
$("#areas").on("change", function(){
    $("#back").prop("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#back").on("click", function(event){
        $("#back").prop("disabled", false)
    }, 10000)
})
```

Comment: This is setting the select box to have a true disabled property, then setting the disabled property to false on the button.